# sort by size opencart

Tags: sorting, size, opencart

I'm trying to add a new sorting method i'e ***"sort by height"*** in opencart.

**A.location is:catalog/model/catalog/product.php -> added p.height here**

```
$sort_data = array(
'pd.name',

'p.model',

'p.quantity',

'p.price',

'rating',

'p.sort_order',

'p.date_added',

'p.height'
);
```

**B. in the same file**

```
elseif($data['sort'] == 'p.height' ){   

    $sql .= " ORDER BY(" . $data['sort'] . ")ASC";

       /*$sql .= "SELECT * FROM". DB_PREFIX . "product p ORDER BY p.height DESC";*/
}
```

**C. location is:/catalog/controller/product/category.php**

```
        $this->data['sorts'][] = array(

            'text'  => $this->language->get('text_size_asc'),

            'value' => 'height-ASC',

            'href'  => $this->url->link('product/category', 'path=' . $this->request->get['path'] . '&sort=height&order=ASC' . $url)

        );
```

Result is i can see "sort by height" in option but nothing happens when i select it returns the default sort value.

Can any one suggest where i am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be `p.height-ASC` not `height-ASC` For the `'value'` key otherwise it does not recognise it. You also need to change `&sort=height` to `&sort=p.height` in the `'url'` key

Comment: You don't need the elseif code that you have there. Just use the standard model file, and add the 'p.height' to the sorts array. That is all that's needed

Comment: @sanki - No problem. Please remember to click the tick on the left to mark this as the answer