# php numbers sort from mysql asc

Tags: php, mysql, sorting, opencart

I need to get order numbers by ASC.
In my mysql table It written with - (ex. 1-2; 2-3; 15-60 etc.)

Now I get order:

15-60; 1-2; 2-3;

why not 1-2; 2-3; 15-60?

I'm making new sorting in my opencart.
Tutorial to make new sorting I used: [sort by size opencart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17755629/sort-by-size-opencart)

Comment: As this is specific to OpenCart it should be asked on  http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/77558/opencart instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try with:

```
SELECT *
FROM yourtable
ORDER BY numbers + 0
```

to automatically cast you VARCHAR column to a number, and apply the order correctly.

Please see fiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9921c/1).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your order numbers are in fact strings of digits interspersed with hyphens, you are getting the string sort order by default.

You can cast strings to integers, but perhaps a better approach is to store order numbers appropriately padded by zero digit characters, so that 15-60, 1-2, 2-3 are stored as 015-060, 001-002, 002-003 (or whatever degree of padding is appropriate). Then the string sort order and numeric sort order will be the same, and you don't need to do casting.

Answer (score 0):

you can also use this

```
 SELECT  *
 FROM yourtable
 ORDER BY CAST(numbers as unsigned)
```

[**DEMO HERE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9921c/6)